# Should I mirror a bitbucket repo that is behind a company VPN?

Tags: git, bitbucket, vpn

I work for a company (C for coders) that is contracted by another company (H for host) to write some code. The host company has an on-premise bitbucket instance that is behind their VPN and is difficult for the coders to get to.

I need help understanding how to get a copy of the bitbucket repo (with all the necessary branches) to our coders network that our team can work with. We would need to clone, push and pull within our network and then on some schedule connect to the hosts vpn and sync. Any ideas if this is possible and if so how I would need to set it up.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: There are a few questions. (1) Are you contractually allowed to copy their repo outside their VPN? My company has the same restriction and I'm not allowed to fork off-premise. (2) How big are these two companies? Are we talking about giving 5 developers access, or 300? In one case, you can ask company to give those 5 devs VPN clients. In the second case, get Ops to bridge your networks (for example - there are many options).

Answer (score 0):

I did that for a previous client.

The key was to:

- have access to a machine connected to the VPN for C to push their code.
- use two branches: `feature1_C` vs. `feature1_H`

That way, C can work on their version of feature1_C, and push it at any time.
Same for H.

That means the reconciliation (merge between feature1_C and feature1_H) can happen whenever C is choosing, instead of being impacted, on each pull, by new code from H: since you are working on two separate branches, you can chose when to merge them.